# How do I make the arrowkeys talk to Form1 instead of the radiobuttons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two radiobuttons inside a groupbox. And a picturebox I want to move around with arrow keys. Without the radiobuttons, everything works completely fine. But when the radiobuttons are added, it's like the radioboxes are selected, and all the arrow-keys do, is just alternating between different radioboxes.

Basically: How do I make the arrowkeys talk to Form1 instead of the radiobuttons?

Comment: Set the forms KeyPreview to true. Without that the focused controls gets key events first.

Comment: May I know whether the answer can solve your issue? If not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey()` like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 1, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            return true;
        case Keys.Right:
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 1, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            return true;
        case Keys.Up:
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - 1);
            return true;
        case Keys.Down:
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 1);
            return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```